# Creating a custom size new window with JS?

Tags: javascript

I have an image that links to another image, which is **672 (W) x 792 (H)** - I would like to know what is the best approach in JS to have this image fit perfectly in a new window, when clicking the image link?

Without fitting the image in a new window, it's aligned left and looks ugly.

Comment: so you want a pop-up which opens seperately from the page the image in a new window, or are you just talking to open it within the page. If its the last one you could use one of the thousand lightboxes out there.

Comment: "*so you want a pop-up which opens seperately from the page the image in a new window*" - Yes exactly.

Comment: I suggest using a lightbox like @supersize mentioned, or if that is really not what want take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

markup:

```
<a href="linktoimg.jpg" target="_blank" onclick="return popup(this.href);">
 <img src="yourimg.jpg"/>
</a>
```

and the js:

```
function popup (url) {
  t_window = window.open(url, "popupwindow", "width=672,height=792,resizable=yes");
  t_window.focus();
  return false;
}
```

but bear in mind that pop-ups are really annoying for some users.

Instead I would recommend you using [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) or any other lightbox.

Comment: I ended up going with [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). Thank you for the suggestion.